# How do I make my chrome app save element changes?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app

Working on a chrome app which basically is a Note taking app, where i can add uls, which function independently as a to do list. I have a pretty big issue on this, probably the most important part. Saving the actual changes made. I have attempted the following:

```
var entire = document.body.innerHTML;
document.onload = chrome.storage.local.get(['full'], function(result) {
entire = result.full; 
console.log(result.full);
});

document.onbeforeunload = 
entire = document.body.innerHTML;
console.log(entire);
chrome.storage.local.set({'full': entire});
```

I have also tried chrome.storage.sync to no avail. I have "chrome.storage.local.set({'full':entire})" on every function that changes the html and event listeners.

On the onbeforeunload console log, I only get the exact same html as is in the original file, instead of what the html was before exiting the application.

Here's a full [github](https://github.com/booperlv/liboop) link.
Thank you in advance! Doing this not only for learning but also because it would be very useful for me as a student.

Comment: HTML doesn't change when inputs/textareas are edited. Only their `value` is changed.

Comment: Do you re-apply the changes after loading them from storage?

Comment: What do you mean by that Ouroborus? Sorry for being a novice, couldn't really get what you meant.

Comment: I will take note of the inputs. Will use an innerhtml = value statement on them. Thank you for that as well! Though i believe that this won't be helping with saving the other elements. Should I be saving the ul container div instead of the body? I'll test some possible solutions when I have the free time!